# DateTimePicker from Material UI change padding after page reload

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I have a issue with DateTimePicker from Material UI. After page reload it loses it's initial padding of 10px for each side.
Once component is rendered for the first time it looks like:
[image]

Once I reload the page it looks like:

[image]

I have inspected it in dev tools and it's this element:
[image]

And I found in dev tools 2 classes where I change padding to 10px ( in dev tools ) it works perfectly
.MuiInputBase-input
.MuiInputBase-root

But once I put those valuse into the code it doesn't work.

```
export const StyledDateTimePicker = styled(DateTimePicker)`
    & .MuiInputBase-root {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    & .MuiInputBase-input {
        padding: 10px;
    }
`;
```

Can You please let me know how to apply those props to the input ? I'm using StyledComponentes in the project.

thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Which version of MUI are you using?

Comment: Mui/lab from where DateTimePicker is installed is : "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.48", this is core version: "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.2",

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by incompatible Mui versions. Try getting rid of `@mui/lab` and install `@material-ui/pickers` instead. https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation

Alternatively, [migrate all your components](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#main-content) to the new version of Mui.

Comment: I have just noticed that I cannot even get into styling possibilities of DateTimePicker. On chrome dev tools it works fine, but when I want to do anything simple, like for example backgroundColor it's not even working. Maybe that could be the reason. Did You come across such situation how to "force" my styles over default ones ?